# Hosting alternative to Nexcess?

Tags: hosting

we have been hosting our Magento 1 site for ten years with Nexcess. Their support has gone down the drain since they joined Liquidweb. We are soon to attempt migration to Magento 2 and would much prefer not to continue with them.
Where would you host your Magento store? We need 50 or more GB of storage, 200GB+ auf Bandwidth, 32GB of ram we receive about 40K visitors per month, around 1.5million hits. 2 domains/websites, IP based county redirects. Currently using nexcess' M-SIP-300 plan for close to 300 USD per month. We use their CDN as well.
What reliable hosting sporting a good responsive customer support would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Magento sites, you should go for Magento Managed Cloud Hosting would be the best option.

It will help you in managing the multiple hosting problems that you may face:

- So, with Managed Hosting is like having your own IT team but at a
  comparatively affordable fee.
- What happens in managed hosting is that you hire a web hosting
  services providing company that takes the entire responsibility of
  security, maintenance, and management of your server.

One of the providers you may consider is Cloiudways.

Comment: Yep, I arrived at this conclusion after spending some time searching and reading.  We choose aspiration hosting and we'll see how this works out for us.

Comment: That's great @Sparc it's great to know that you comes up with a solution. Would be great if you share some valuable information with some key points that you want to highlight for future audiences with the solution that you choose.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use Magento Cloud its the best for the Magento Sites.

Comment: Yes, I am gravitating towards managed cloud hosting or similar.
Can you recommend a provider and what is your experience?

Comment: I rely on the Magento cloud or Ecritel. But I will prefer you to go Magento cloud.