# Magento 2 Hosting

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.4, hosting

I am running 2.3.5 and in the process of moving to 2.4.6. We are currently using Webscale (formally Magemojo) for hosting and have been for several years.

I am Looking at Nexcess.

I am not sure what all my current plan consist of with the exception of 25gb Disk Space and paying $98 a month. I have been very satisfied with them till now.
I was wondering if anyone has had issue with Nexcess and how they may compare to Webscale as for as site performance, support, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

Were there any issues with Webscale (formally Magemojo)?

What were the hosting features of previous host?

There may be various factors you should think of before choosing new host for your website.

- Server Location
- Magento 2 Security
- Pricing Plan
- Server Scalability
- Cache Technologies etc.

Based on the review of https://cybernews.com/best-web-hosting/nexcess-review, Nexcess has **3.8 rating**, while there are many others which have much better reputation for Magento hosting.

I would recommend checking Cloudways once. Based on various reviews they are the best for pay-as-you-go plans.

They offer options to pick an infrastructure provider from DigitalOcean, Vultr, Linode, Google Cloud, or AWS.

Earlier Nexcess was a good option for Magento, but based on reviews of some users ([Hosting alternative to Nexcess?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361964/hosting-alternative-to-nexcess?rq=1)) I would recommend checking other options as well.